# C# WPF Put children of custom control to specific grid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some question in wpf and user control creating.
I have simple Menu control which includes Grid, Image(0 Column) and TextBlock(1 Column).

The promlem Im stucked with is how to put all children of my control to another grid near parent control.

This is demo code of user control:

```
<UserControl x:Name="userControl" x:Class="Yo.Controls.mItem"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="400">
<Grid x:Name="m_Grid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=userControl, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="305"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image x:Name="img" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="txt" Grid.Column="2"/>

    <Grid x:Name="sub_Grid" Visibility="Hidden" Background="#78000000" Margin="-450,0,50,0" MouseLeftButtonUp="img_Check" MouseEnter="grid_Enter" MouseLeave="grid_Leave"/>

</Grid>
```

Where sub_Grid is the place where children must be placed.

```
        <Controls:mItem Grid.Row="0" Text="Some txt" IsCheckable="False">
            <Controls:mItem Text="Its Child" IsCheckable="False"/>
        </Controls:mItem>
```

So this code will place Control with Text Its Child to sub_Grid

Comment: You could have done this using MVVM. Your textbox and Image can be an VM object for DataTemplates. Then the Grid should have an ItemsControl child that shares the same ItemSource.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should nest the controls within subGrid and then define columns for the sub grid. I am going on a wimp here by suggesting the following because I don't entirely understand your question:

```
 <Grid x:Name="m_Grid" Background="Red">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="305"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="sub_Grid" Background="Blue" Margin="0,0,50,0" 
          MouseLeftButtonUp="img_Check" MouseEnter="grid_Enter" MouseLeave="grid_Leave" Grid.Column="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image x:Name="img" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txt" Grid.Column="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid
```